# Why is it so common with member methods instead of static methods?

Tags: php

I have seen this in a lot of third party libraries. Right now, I'm dealing with Lcobucci/JWT but I've seen it in other places too.

So as a concrete example, let's take an encoder in the above mentioned library. There we have this method in class `JoseEncoder` [source](https://github.com/lcobucci/jwt/blob/5.1.x/src/Encoding/JoseEncoder.php)

```
public function base64UrlEncode(string $data): string
{
    return SodiumBase64Polyfill::bin2base64(
        $data,
        SodiumBase64Polyfill::SODIUM_BASE64_VARIANT_URLSAFE_NO_PADDING,
    );
}
```

which (if I'm correct) forces me to do

```
$val = (new JoseEncoder)->base64UrlEncode($data);
```

instead of

```
$val = JoseEncoder::base64UrlEncode($data);
```

As far as I can see, the method `JoseEncoder::base64UrlEncode()` just calls `SodiumBase64Polyfill::bin2base64()` which in turn calls a pure function that's not a member of a class and is called `sodium_bin2base64()`.

To me, it seems obvious that it would be much better to declare `JoseEncoder::base64UrlEncode()` as a static method. But since it's so common with non-static methods in cases like this, I get the feeling that there is something I don't understand.

Comment: `JoseEncoder` implements `Encoder` interface. And therefore can be replaced with anything else that implements this interface in a single line of code with DI. With your `JoseEncoder::base64UrlEncode` replacing it with `SomeOtherGuyEncoder` will lead to changes in code in many places.

Comment: It's a matter of style, object-oriented vs. "procedural". Static methods are harder to test and generally less fixible as @u_mulder pointed out above.

Comment: For this very specific case I think this [commit message](https://github.com/lcobucci/jwt/commit/90386f7d18f7cc6c7ab75e0362362370f5a9ff93) is relevant, related to [this](https://github.com/lcobucci/jose-parsing): "_We extracted this thinking about supporting many other packages for the JOSE standards. The reality, though, was that we created more work without benefiting from the separation._" That library was then back merged in, but the interfaces were just kept, probably for simplicity.

Comment: Meh. I rather like static functions. But it is a matter of style, and when building a library that requires flexibility, using constructors and inheritance is the way to go (although I suppose the function that eventually gets called to do the work could be declared static... it's always nice when the developer can choose and the library is not forcing you to do just the one thing)

Comment: @JonathanDavidArndt I also prefer static methods. But unfortunately, I've run into issues when I need to mock them.

Comment: *snarf* yep! you are stuck with member methods then -- it's fine, this is an area where you just have to go with the flow